# How to parse date string to Date?

Tags: java

```
/Date(13863838400000-0400)/
```

I get the date format as above, how would i display in MM-DD-YY. Below is what i tried.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String target = "/Date(13863838400000-0400)/";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date result =  df.parse(target);  
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

I am not getting the parsed date...

Comment: How would you *expect* that `SimpleDateFormat` to parse the text you've given it? It doesn't look remotely like the format you've provided.

Comment: The DateFormat pattern must represent the format of what you want to parse, not the the expected result

Comment: I think the input date is time in milliseconds followed by timezone

Comment: Can you tell us what is the expected output

Comment: It should be Month-Day-Year... [12-12-2012]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the given additional information

```
String target = "/Date(13863838400000-0400)/";
long millis = Long.parseLong(target.substring(target.indexOf("(") + 1,
        target.indexOf("-")));
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(df.format(new Date(millis)));
```

Comment: This is not considering the -0400.

Answer (score 1):

Looks the date is provided in milliseconds (LONG). Hence use as below

```
        Date result = new Date(13863838400000l-0400);
        System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: How would i remove the /Date(13863838400000-0400)/, so that i get that in milliseconds

Comment: There are many ways, easiest way is just substring..  but make sure that you confirm with the source that this is indeed milliseconds   String target = "/Date(13863838400000-0400)/";
      Date result = new Date(Long.parseLong(target.substring(6,target.length()-7)) - Long.parseLong(target.substring(target.length()-6,target.length()-2)));
      System.out.println(result);